# Can we have models who depends on each other?

Tags: java, rest, oop, design-patterns

```
class Parent {
    long id;
    List<Child> children;   
}

class Child {
    long id;
    Parent parent;
}
```

**GET /parents/1, here have to show children of Parent 1**

**GET /children/101  here have to show Parent of Child 101**

I actually didnt like above circular dependency design, but I am not understanding how to fix above scenario. Need some help to fix above design issue.

And also iam not sure whether can we have DTOs who depends on each other? Is this correct design?

Comment: Sometimes, you have to have 2 classes depend on each other, although it's not always necessary for child nodes to know their parents

Comment: You could break the dependency by introducing a model that depends on both and mirrors Parent/Child-Relations.

Comment: @Fildor Any example please?

Comment: `class ParentChildRelation{ long id; long parentId; long childId; }`, while removing the List and Parent fields from Parent and Child. Like you would do it in a Relational DB Model.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks. But I have neven seen like above, anywhere...

Comment: @Fildor I am actually asking for UI response, not from DB perspective..

Comment: Ok, then above design is not really "Circular". I'd call it "mutual". It's totally OK, though for a UI facing design. You just asked for a way to avoid it, so that's what you would do in a DB to avoid this.

Comment: @Fildor  My actual problem is: I am using Mapstruct, where I could not able to map objects from model to DTO, due to above Circular/Mutual issue...

Comment: Never heard of it. You should probably add this to the question. Add the library in use and what it is complaining about. Is it this one: https://mapstruct.org/ ?

Comment: I guess I see where this is going. MapStruct needs to have the Parent Mapping to create the Child code. But it needs the Child Mapping to create the Parent code... right? I am guessing, there must be some way to do it if you search the docs. That would be a pretty common thing.

Comment: They do have an example "with cycles" but that is how to deal with "self-reference", that is cycles in graphs, for example.

Comment: @Fildor Ya, I am still looking into some mapstruct examples to fix above circular dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can have models that depend on each other. This is widely used in hibernate. Your example is like one to many mapping.

Comment: Okay, I am actually asking for UI response, not from DB perspective. any idea on how to fix on UI perspective

Comment: My actual problem is: I am using Mapstruct, where I could not able to map objects from model to DTO, due to above Circular/Mutual issue...